# VSTO: Get Text Cursor position (X/Y)

Tags: .net, vsto

Is it possible to get the text cursor's position (the X and Y coordinates) within a Word Document (not the mouse cursor)? Basically I need to know where the text cursor is currently located on the screen. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check that link it might help out

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.word.vba.general/browse_thread/thread/a4aab83eca83ddc3/7793412e01a43bc8?tvc=2#7793412e01a43bc8